# How to add an EventListener to a thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, serial-port, event-listener

I've created a Java thread that reads data through serial port. The main parts of the code is given below:

```
public class dthread implements Runnable{

public dthread(CommPortIdentifier portId)implements SerialPortEventListener {    

    try {

    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),TIME_OUT);
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

    // open the streams
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));

    serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

} catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}  
}

  public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent){
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        String inputLine =null;
        try {
            // String inputLine=null;
            if (input.ready())  {
                                inputLine = input.readLine();
                                System.out.println(inputLine);             
                                }

            } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e.toString());}
}

}

   public void run() {}

}
```

**portId** - contains commportidentifier info. about the connected COM port; from another class.

`public dthread(CommPortIdentifier portId)implements SerialPortEventListener {` clearly, this is wrong. How should I implement SerialPortEvent in my code?

Comment: Ouch. I take it you haven't been working with Java for long?

Comment: @Kayaman is it that bad? :D :D just trying to read data from an Arduino to  a Java program.

Comment: Well, judging from you trying to have your *constructor* implement an interface, you missed a couple basic lessons. Multiple interfaces are implemented by comma separating them, i.e. `implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener`.

Comment: You have created a class that implements `Runnable`, but you've given it a `run()` method that does nothing.  If your class had "fake" or "dummy" or "null" in its name, then I would not be surprised; but since it doesn't...  Why you need a `Runnable` that does nothing?

Comment: I don't know what library the `SerialPort` class comes from, so I could be completely off-base here, but I expect that the library is going to create a thread of its own that will spend all its time waiting for bytes to arrive on the serial port.  I expect that when bytes arrive, it is _that_ thread, and not any thread of yours that will call your `serialEvent(...)` method.

Comment: Problem was with my poor knowledge in syntax. Kayman's `implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener` tip solved it.